# VBA Excel Nested For Loop (write numbers down column)

Tags: excel, vba

Nested loop sort of works. The problem - I can't figure out how to make the loop move on to the next block of cells (B11:B20); it's simply rewriting values in to range(B1:B10). My thoughts are that I may not need a nested loop but I can't wrap my head around a solution.

```
Sub insertNum()

Dim sheetOne As Worksheet
Set sheetOne = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim i, j As Long
For i = 1 To sheetOne.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To 10
        Select Case j
            Case 1 To 5
            sheetOne.Cells(j, 2).Value = "2"
            Case 6 To 10
            sheetOne.Cells(j, 2).Value = "3"
         End Select
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give a better explanation of what you are trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to have loop "j" insert either 1 or 2 depending on it's iteration over a range of 10 cells. e.g., B1:B5 = 2, B6:B10 = 3. The loop should then jump to the next range (B11:B20) and perform the same operation.Loop i is counting the total number of used cells within the worksheet.

Comment: I tried finding a way to write "for every 10 iterations of i, do this" (what j is performing), but I've had no luck

Comment: Your main issue is you don't have i doing anything in your loop whatsoever. My answer should be somewhat of a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want, I think. I tested it and it just switches between 2 and 3 every 5 rows.

```
Sub insertNum()

Dim sheetOne As Worksheet
Set sheetOne = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = 1 To sheetOne.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step 10
For j = 1 To 10
    Select Case j
        Case 1 To 5
        sheetOne.Cells(i + j - 1, 2).Value = "2"
        Case 6 To 10
        sheetOne.Cells(i + j - 1, 2).Value = "3"
     End Select
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, works perfect. I thought that I would have to do something like this (i + j - 1), but I've never had to it before. This is great!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this without using any loops in your code, Increasing the time it takes to execute by about 400% in this case by using the following code:

```
Sub insertNumNoLoopSample()
With [B1:B50000]
    .FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(ISNA(MATCH(RIGHT(ROW(),1), {""1"",""2"",""3"",""4"",""5""},0)),3,2)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
End Sub
```

Tested with a range of B1:B50000 running each code (other answer and this) my code took on average 0.41 seconds to execute while the other answer took on average 2.1 seconds to execute.

You can use the code as is, or modify the With line and add in the range you wish to run the code on, if you want to use the used range instead (this is not recommended) then you could replace

`With [B1:B50000]`

and use the below instead.

`With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("B")`

The best way to get the last used row instead of using used range if you don't know what the last row will be, or if it will change will be to use the following:

```
Sub NoLoopSample()
Dim lastRow As Long
'Replace The A with the Column of your data that 
'will the longest amount of data.
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 

With Range("B1:B" & lastRow)
    .FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(ISNA(MATCH(RIGHT(ROW(),1), {""1"",""2"",""3"",""4"",""5""},0)),3,2)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a great solution. However, the actual data that I will be working with contains 99900 rows with blocks of 300 that will be divided in to chucks of 100. I'm going to try this out though using a "_" for readability (I tend to lose track where I'm at when dealing with the ")" character).

Comment: I'll definitely keep this method in my "cookbook".

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be:

```
Sub insertNum()

Dim sheetOne As Worksheet
Set sheetOne = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim i, j As Long
For i = 1 To sheetOne.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To 10
        Select Case j
            Case 1 To 5
            sheetOne.Cells(j, i).Value = "2"
            Case 6 To 10
            sheetOne.Cells(j, i).Value = "3"
        End Select
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

It seems to me that you are hard-coded assigning the row (2) into your loop. I take it that i is the row looper, but you never use that value to assign your cell.

Comment: He hardcoded the column (B), not the row. This will switch his columns every iteration now, won't it?

Comment: I was using i as a statement to address every used row within the worksheet. Originally I had placed i instead of j within the select case statement but it didn't work as for every iteration of i, j iterates 10 times. The i in (j,i) places values length-wise over 20 columns, I'm just trying to go down 1 column, "B".